# Show that root $x\equiv 0$ of $\dfrac{dx}{dt}=F(t,x)$ is uniformly stable (uniformly asymptotically stable)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

I have a problem:

> For the system of equations: $$\bf \dfrac{dx}{dt}=F(t,x) \tag 1$$ where $F$ is continuous in $I \times D \subset\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^n$ and
>   $F(t,0)\equiv0$, $F(t+\omega,x)=F(t,x), \omega >0$, it means that $F$ is periodic function.
>   Prove that, if root $x\equiv 0$ of (1) is **stable** (**asymptotically
>   stable**) then it is *uniformly stable* (*uniformly asymptotically
>   stable*).

- **Uniformly Stable**: If any given $\epsilon >0$, $\exists \delta=\delta(\epsilon)>0$:
  $$\|x(t_0)\|< \delta \implies \|x(t)\|<\epsilon, \forall t\ge t_0 >0$$
- I have thought about my problem, I used the definition uniformly stable/ uniformly asymptotically stable.

But I'm having trouble when I try to find a solution to the problem, and I still have no solution. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: A few questions:  what is $f$?  Or perchance did you mean to write $F(t + \omega, x) = F(t, x)$?  In which case, are we to take $\omega \ne 0$, so that $F$ is periodic in $t$?  Also, do we have $F(t, 0) = 0$?

Comment: Also, is $F$ Lipschitz continuous in $x$?

Comment: What **is** f after all? Please fix, if you want an answer.

Comment: The assumption as I wrote (I posted from my book), and all that we have.

Comment: OK, OK, based on **kimtahe6**'s comment that the assumption was posted from her book, I think it is safe to assume the little $f$ should have been capitalized, i.e., $F$; the question makes a lot more sense that way.

Comment: **kimtahe6**, still would like to know if $F$ is Lipschitz continuous in $x$.  Can you help with this?  Cheers!

Comment: **Why** did you confirm $F$ is Lipschitz?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution by **[José L. Massera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Luis_Massera)**

1/ $x \equiv 0$ is **uniformly stable**.

- We assume that If $x \equiv 0$ is not uniformly stable, there would be an $\epsilon >0$ and sequences $\{x_{0n}\}$, $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_{0n}=0,t_{0n},t_n,t_{0n} \le t_n$, such that:$$\left \|F(t_n,t_{0n},x_{0n})  \right \| \ge \epsilon$$
- Assuming that the period is $1$ , let $\tau_{0n}=t_{0n}-\left \lfloor t_{0n} \right \rfloor \le 1$, $\tau_n=t_n-\left \lfloor t_{0n} \right \rfloor \ge \tau_{0n} \ge 0;$

and we have

$$\left \|F(\tau_n,\tau_{0n},x_{0n})  \right \| =\left \|F(t_n,t_{0n},x_{0n})  \right \| \ge \epsilon; (1)$$
- But $x_{1n}=F(0,\tau_{0n},x_{0n})$ exists for $n$ sufficiently large and tends to zero and we would have 
$$\left \|F(\tau_n,0,x_{1n})  \right \|=\left \|F(\tau_n,\tau_{0n},x_{0n})  \right \| \ge \epsilon; (2) $$  against the stability assumption. $\blacksquare$

I don't understand (1) and (2). I think we must use If $x(t)$ is solution then $y(t)=x(t+\omega)$ too.

If you understand this solution, you can explain to me? anyone? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Here's the solution (my professor)**:

$\blacktriangle $. Prove that $x\equiv 0$ is **Uniformly Stable**:

- Because $x\equiv 0$ is **stable**, so
  $\forall \varepsilon >0, \forall t_0 \ge 0, \exists \eta (t_0,\varepsilon ) >0 $ such that $\left \| x_0 \right \|<\eta$ then $$\left \| x(t) \right \|<\varepsilon ,\forall t \ge t_0 \ge 0$$
- Because $x(t;\tau,u)$ is continuous (follow $(\tau,u)$), so: $\exists \delta_1>0: \left | \tau-t_0 \right |<\delta_1,\left \| u-x_0 \right \|<\delta_1, \forall t_0,\tau \in \left [ 0,\omega \right ]$ then $$\left \| x(t;\tau,u) -x(t;t_0,x_0)\right \|<\dfrac{\eta}{2}, \forall t \in \left [ 0,\omega \right ]$$
- Because $x(t;t_0,x_0)$ is continuous (follow $t$), so $\exists \delta_2>0$ such that $$\left | t-t_0 \right |<\delta_2 \implies \left \| x(t;t_0,x_0)-x_0 \right \|<\eta$$
- We take $\delta(t_0)=\min \left \{ \delta_1,\delta_2,\eta \right \}$.

Whence, $\forall t' \in \left ( t_0-\delta(t_0),t_0+\delta(t_0) \right ), \left \| x_0 \right \|<\delta(t_0)$ we consider solution $x(t;t',x_0)$ of $(1)$:
$\left \| x(t_0;t',x_0) \right \|\le \left \|x(t_0;t',x_0)-x(t_0;t_0,x_0)  \right \|+ \left \|x(t_0;t_0,x_0)  \right \|<\dfrac{\eta}{2}+\dfrac{\eta}{2}=\eta$ then $$ \left \| x(t;t_0,x(t_0;t',x_0)) \right \|<\epsilon$$

- Therefore, $\forall s \in \left [ 0,\omega \right ],\exists \delta (s)>0$ such that $\forall t_0 \in \left [ s-\delta(s),s+\delta(s) \right ], \forall x_0: \left \| x_0 \right \|<\delta$ then $$\left \| x(t;t_0,x_0) \right \|<\epsilon, \forall t\ge t_0$$
- Thus, we have $$\bigcup_{s \in \left [ 0,\omega \right ]}\left ( s-\delta(s),s+\delta(s) \right )\supset \left [ 0,\omega \right ]$$
  Hence, $\exists s_1,\ldots, s_m$ such that $$\bigcup_{k=\overline{1,m}}\left ( s_k-\delta(s_k),s_k+\delta(s_k) \right )\supset \left [ 0,\omega \right ]$$
- We let $\delta :=\min_{k=\overline{1,m}} \delta (s_k)>0$. We consider any solution $x(t;t_0,x_0)$ of $(1)$: $$\left \| x_0 \right \|< \delta, \exists m \in \Bbb Z:\tau=t_0+m\omega\in \left [ 0, \omega \right ]$$
- By taking $y(t)=x(t-m\omega) $ is a solution of $(1)$. Whence,  $$\left \| y(\tau) \right \|=\left \| x(\tau-m\omega) \right \|=\left \| x_0 \right \|< \delta
  \implies \left \| y(t) \right \|<\epsilon, \forall t\ge \tau
  \implies \left \| x(t) \right \|<\epsilon, \forall t\ge t_0 \blacksquare $$

===================================

$\blacktriangle $ But how can we show that $x\equiv 0$ is **Uniformly asymptotically Stable**?

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!